# Parsing by number and moving number into existing column in R

Tags: r, parsing, merge

I have some messy test data and am looking to clean it up. Below is an example of the relevant columns I am working with:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(Test_Name = c("Super Test", "Amazing Test", "57 Amazing Test", "Super Test",
 "Excellent Test", "Multiple Combined Tests (22, 23, 24)", "2431 Super Test"), Test_Number = 
c(2431,57,NA,2431,123,NA,NA))
```

I would like to ideally pull the numbers that are in the Test_Name column and move them to the Test_Number column. Ideally, it would look like this:

```
    ideal <- data.frame(Test_Name = c("Super Test", "Amazing Test", "Amazing Test", "Super Test",
 "Excellent Test", "Multiple Combined Tests (22, 23, 24)", "Super Test"), Test_Number = 
c(2431,57,57,2431,123,NA,2431))
```

I'm not sure how to parse out just the number in the front, without parsing out every single word. The number of words for each test also varies, so it yields a different number of columns. Additionally, once parsed, I am not sure how I would merge the column to the Test_Number column without affecting what is currently in that column. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you really have no `NA` values in your data? `NA` and `"NA"` are very different.

Comment: @r2evans - I do have NA values - just made the edits to my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using tidyverse

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Test_Number = case_when(
        str_detect(Test_Name,"^[0-9]{1,10}") ~ str_extract(Test_Name,"^[0-9]{1,10}"),
        TRUE ~ Test_Number
    ))
df2
```

Solution uses case_when to detect if the string in Test name begins with numbers. If yes, extracts the string, else, preserve the value.

Comment: Thank you! Just tried this solution on my data and it worked really well!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
nums <- regmatches(df1$Test_Name, gregexpr("\\d+", df1$Test_Name))
nums <- unlist(replace(nums, sapply(nums, length) != 1L, NA_character_))
nums
# [1] NA     NA     "57"   NA     NA     NA     "2431"
df1$Test_Number2 <- ifelse(is.na(nums), df1$Test_Number, nums)
df1
#                              Test_Name Test_Number Test_Number2
# 1                           Super Test        2431         2431
# 2                         Amazing Test          57           57
# 3                      57 Amazing Test          NA           57
# 4                           Super Test        2431         2431
# 5                       Excellent Test         123          123
# 6 Multiple Combined Tests (22, 23, 24)          NA           NA
# 7                      2431 Super Test          NA         2431
```

I'm assuming that "length 1" is an important predicate to you, since you avoided `(22,23,24)`.

If you have "real" `NA` values (not literal strings `"NA"`), then a slightly-safer alternative might be:

```r
ifelse(is.na(df1$Test_Number), nums, df1$Test_Number)
```

Comment: Thanks - this solution worked and I appreciate the two options, depending on the type of missing data.

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Test_Number = if_else(is.na(Test_Number), 
                               as.numeric(str_extract(Test_Name, "^[0-9]*")), 
                               Test_Number))

                             Test_Name Test_Number
1                           Super Test        2431
2                         Amazing Test          57
3                      57 Amazing Test          57
4                           Super Test        2431
5                       Excellent Test         123
6 Multiple Combined Tests (22, 23, 24)          NA
7                      2431 Super Test        2431
```